# Spring cloud Config server not pulling latest commit from git

Tags: java, spring, config, pcf, spring-cloud-config-server

Spring cloud config server was working fine earlier but since last 1 month whatever new commits we have been making in git it is not getting updated in config server. It shows old commit version in hash name in pcf.Synchronize mirrors also shows status as failed.

Answer (score 1):

If you haven't found an answer yet, I just had the same issue.

It could be a simple case of your GIT credentials having expired - we were using a generated username/password from AzureDevops and while it didn't mention an expiration date, the problem went away when I generated new ones and updated the config server with them.

You can simply do

cf update-service your-config-server -c '{"git": { "uri": "url-to-your-repo", "searchPaths": "{application}", "username": "username" ,"password": "password" } }'

Then try to refresh the mirrors again.

PS: The 'searchpaths' may be different for your setup.